# installshield object is missing in InstallShield 2011

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

We moved our build server machine to a new machine. In the new build server, we have Installed the Installshield 2011 as the previous server. But in the new machine, the Install Shield wizard shows, the Install Shield Object is missing. If I try to register the objects, some of the objects are not properly mapped to the corresponding feature. They still show the missing icon.How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple paths where the objects are kept.

1. Check in program files\installshield xx\Objects
2. Check in program files\Common files\installshield\objects

Copy your objects to these two folders and reopen the installshield. Try rebuilding the project.